# Is Paul referring to a specific person in 2 Cor 2:5-8

Tags: paul, 2-corinthians

Is Paul referring to a specific person in 2 Corinthians 2:5-8? If so, what is the “punishment inflicted by the majority” that verse 6 talks about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, were are not explicitly told to whom this specifically refers.  However, the likely candidate is the same person in as in 1 Cor 5 who perused an incestuous relationship and had to be disfellowshiped from the local congregation as the punishment, 1 Cor 5:13.

Ellicott observes:

> (5) But if any have caused grief.—The man who had been the chief cause
> of his sorrow is now prominent in his thoughts. He will not name him.
> He is, as in 1Corinthians 5:1-5, and here in 2Corinthians 2:7, “a
> man,” “such a one.”

Barnes:

> If any have caused grief - There is doubtless here an allusion to the
> incestuous person. But it is very delicately done. He does not mention
> him by name. There is not anywhere an allusion to his name; nor is it
> possible now to know it. Is this not a proof that the names of the
> offending brethren in a church should not be put on the records of
> sessions, and churches, and presbyteries, to be handed down to
> posterity? Paul does not here either expressly refer to such a person.
> He makes his remark general, that it might be as tender and kind to
> the offending brother as possible. They would know whom he meant, but
> they had already punished him, as Paul supposed, enough, and note all
> that he said in regard to him was as tender as possible, and suited,
> as much as possible, to conciliate his feelings and allay his grief.
> He did not harshly charge him with sin; he did not use any abusive or
> severe epithets; but he gently insinuates that he "had caused grief;"
> he had pained the hearts of his brethren.

Cambridge:

> 5. he hath not grieved me, but in part: that I may not overcharge you all] According to the A. V. the meaning is that the Apostle, anxious
>    not to lay too heavy a charge at the door of the Corinthian Church, to
>    which (see 1 Corinthians 5:2; 1 Corinthians 5:6) he considers the
>    guilt to attach, declares that the offender has only pained him to a
>    certain extent. But the words are capable of another rendering, ‘But
>    if any one hath caused pain, it is not me whom he has pained, but to a
>    certain extent—not to press too heavily upon him—all of you.’ This
>    rendering is susceptible of two interpretations (1) he has caused pain
>    to the whole community; but not to be too severe upon him, the Apostle
>    is willing to admit that this pain is to a certain extent lessened by
>    the mutual sympathy of the members of the Church. Or perhaps (2) there
>    is a slight reproof here, implying, as in 1 Corinthians 5:2, that the
>    Corinthians had not sufficiently felt the disgrace brought on them all
>    by such a crime. Cf. ch. 2 Corinthians 1:14. The Apostle thus, with no
>    less adroitness than simple honesty, places the personal aspect of the
>    question in the background, and deals with it as a matter of public
>    principle, with which every member of the Church is as intimately
>    concerned as himself. The whole passage refers to the offender
>    mentioned in 1 Corinthians 5.